# Heroku CI: Run tests only on pull requests

Tags: heroku

I've used Travis for some time, and are now experimenting with Heroku CI for a one of our Rails projects. It works well, but it automatically runs the tests for **all** pushes to the GitHub repo.

Ideally, I'd like to run tests only when a pull request is made, not when code is just pushed to a branch. Travis works this way. I've read the docs but cannot see where this can be configured.

At the moment I am manually disabling the CI, but this is hardly ideal. The alternative is to pay for tests which are not yet needed.

[image]

Can Heroku CI be configured this way?

Comment: Looking for the same. Looks like heroku lacks these options currently.